# Unable to run dnx console App

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm, dnu

I have followed this [link](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html#creating-a-console-app) to run a dnx console app. I created two files Program.cs and project.json with the content as mentioned in the link

Here is the sequence of commands that i executed

```
    F:\first-dnx> dnvm list

    Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
    ------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
           1.0.0-beta6       clr     x86          win
           1.0.0-beta6       coreclr x64          win
      *    1.0.0-beta8-15530 clr     x86          win             default

F:\first-dnx> dnu restore
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta8-15530

Restoring packages for F:\first-dnx\project.json
  CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
Writing lock file F:\first-dnx\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 490ms elapsed

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\sam\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/
    https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
F:\first-dnx> dnu build
```

The project got built successfully but when i am trying to run the app
below exception is thrown

```
F:\first-dnx> dnx . run
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load application or execute command '.'. Available commands: ConsoleApp1.
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ThrowEntryPointNotfoundException(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, Exception innerException)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
F:\first-dnx> dnx . ConsoleApp1
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load application or execute command '.'. Available commands: ConsoleApp1.
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ThrowEntryPointNotfoundException(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, Exception innerException)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
F:\first-dnx>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to add the `.` to specify the base path anymore. Try:

```
dnx run
```

This was changed in beta7. See: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/52.

Comment: `dnx run` is a shorthand for executing the entry point of the current project. It should start `ConsoleApp1`.

Comment: dnx command(Here consoleApp1 in project.json) should also run the app, rt?

Comment: but is is throwing the same error as mentioned above, any idea?

Comment: What does `dnx ConsoleApp1` output?

Comment: Now i got it, i should point the name of the command to point to the name of the folder. After changing,   "commands": { "ConsoleApp1": "first-dnx"}  it works.Thanks!!!